# Title casing on secondary navigation within users pages

Tags: bug

Noticing that secondary navigation throughout Stack Overflow is generally lowercase, but this is not true for certain pages, specifically within /users:

**Login / Signup Screen**

[image: Login Screen]

**Profile**

[image]

Is this by design or bug?

Comment: OK, you're right.